# Removing points from an array on a data map between two historical timepoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I currently have 2 "data maps" for different time periods (1901-2021, 1979-2021). I would like to subtract the gridded points in the maps to show a difference between where areas have had more precipitation. I am unsure what I can look up to research this. Please advise.

Thank you

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy import feature as cf
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import netCDF4
import scipy
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import netCDF4


in_file = r'/Users/shawnpreston/Desktop/my_project_DO_NOT_ERASE/precip/cru_ts4.06.1901.2021.pre.dat.nc'


Data=xr.open_dataset(in_file)
precip_data=Data['pre']

NHNA=precip_data.sel(lon = np.arange(-128.715, -64.557, 0.5), lat = np.arange(24, 50, 0.5), method='nearest')

#taking the years from Dec 1978 - December 2021
study_date = NHNA[935:1452]

#Dec 1949-Dec 1979
study_date_1950_1980 = NHNA[587:948]

#Dec 1989- Dec 2020
study_date_1990_2020 = NHNA[1067:1440]

seas_nhna = study_date.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
#1950-1980
season_nhna = study_date_1950_1980.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
#1990-2020
seasons_nhna = study_date_1990_2020.groupby('time.season').mean('time')


#Taking all the years to show difference
Seas_NHNA = NHNA.groupby('time.season').mean('time')



#plotting 1901-2021 precip
Seas_NHNA.plot.contourf(x = 'lon', y = 'lat', col = 'season', col_wrap = 2, cmap = 'Blues', vmin = 0, vmax = 200)

#plotting 1979-2021 precip
seas_nhna.plot.contourf(x = 'lon', y = 'lat', col = 'season', col_wrap = 2, cmap = 'Blues', vmin = 0, vmax = 200)
```

[image]
[image]

I have tried setting the plots to a variable and subtracting them.

Comment: What happened when you tried setting the plots to a variable and subtracting them?

Comment: I end up getting this error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'FacetGrid' and 'FacetGrid'

But I am not using Seaborn

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rename your variables, as they are a bit confusing.

According to the [Xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/) documentation, you should be able to subtract one data set from the other.

If you want to compare the 1950-1980 data to the mean:

```py
season_all  = study_date.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
season_5080 = study_date_1950_1980.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
differences = season_5080 - season_all
differences.plot.contourf(...)
```

You can look at the following example where they do something similar:  [Xarray monthly-means](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/monthly-means.html)

To reply to your comment, Xarray has a [Facetgrid](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.FacetGrid.html) object used when plotting, so that might be the source of your error message.

Comment: Thanks! I changed things up and it worked.